# Ajax auto complete state and country name when user enter city name with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**HTML Form**

```
<form role="form" id="registration_form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">sign up</button> 
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script > 
    $(function(){
        $("#location").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo SITE_ROOT;?>xyz/signup/autocomplete" 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
function autocomplete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $city = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->registration_model->get_location($city);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function get_location($city)
{
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->like('name', $city); 
    $this->db->limit('6'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('cities');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){ 
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
        } 

        echo json_encode($row_set);  
    }
}
```

Problem:How can I display auto-complete state name and country name after city name when user can enter city name?
output of this code: 
if you type s in text box this code gives 6 names in which s latter is comes.

Comment: can you add the output of  echo json_encode($row_set);   what it is returning

Comment: its give 6 city name according you search

Comment: if you type 's' in text box this code gives 6 names in which s latter is comes.